# Ember and external js scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

Ok, i'm a really newbie to Ember JS, but i'm having a play and working my way through things.
So far I'm really liking it, but…

I wanted to use something like: https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus, which created a masonry style layout.

I have create the route, and the navigation to that view, but… how do you apply the effect?

Normally a:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.Collage').collagePlus();
});
```

would do the job at the bottom of the page, but i'm guessing popping in a:

```
App.GridRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
afterModel: function(){
$('.Collage').collagePlus();
}
});
```

Might be better, but that's not working…

any help, pointers on this welcome, be gentle as i'm not understanding it quite yet!

PS. i'm also using bootstrap and bootstrap ember (probably doesn't matter…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to do it it's the View, handling the `didInsertElement` event. I believe the View it's a good place to isolate any logic related to the DOM.

```
App.GridView = Ember.Route.extend({
    classNames: ['Collage'],

    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$().collagePlus();
    }
});
```

A useful [link](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method__):

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, made sense, though I'm still having issues:

Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'one' ember-1.2.0.js:3231
Assertion failed: You must pass instance or subclass of View ember-1.2.0.js:3231
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'renderToBuffer'

Comment: Hang-on, i might be ok, i hadn't defined the view on the template {{#view App.GridView}}