# Ember.js and {{each}}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

After my first post being answered in regards [external scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684879/ember-and-external-js-scripts/20685411?noredirect=1#20685411), i have now got an issue with {{each}} pulling the data in. The static option works, but the each version doesn't. Again any help on this welcome...

Also as a side note, when the each is rendered i'm getting the  also styled.

Please take a look a the jsfiddle (though https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus isn't included, so wont work in current state...), any help welcome...

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="container">{{outlet}}</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <h3>By Ember each</h3>

    <h4>Each</h4>
    {{#view App.GridView}}
            {{#each}}
                    <img src="{{unbound src}}"/>
            {{/each}}
    {{/view}}

    <h4>Static</h4>
    {{#view App.GridView2}}
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180/A7DBD8/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x300/E0E4CC/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/472x500/F38630/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/540x360/FA6900/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600/ECD078/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x120/D95B43/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/C02942/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x500/542437/ffffff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/450x300/53777A/ffffff"/>      
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

**JS**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Videos;
    }
});



App.GridView = Ember.View.extend({

    classNames: ['Collage'],

 didInsertElement: function(){
    this._super();
        this.$().removeWhitespace().collagePlus();
        //this.$().collagePlus();
    }
});

App.GridView2 = Ember.View.extend({

    classNames: ['Collage'],

 didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$().removeWhitespace().collagePlus();
        //this.$().collagePlus();
    }
});
```

**DATA**

```
var Videos = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/320x180/A7DBD8/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/320x300/E0E4CC/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 4,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/472x500/F38630/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 5,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/540x360/FA6900/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 6,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/800x600/ECD078/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 7,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/400x120/D95B43/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 8,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/300x300/C02942/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 9,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/320x500/542437/ffffff'
},
{
    id: 10,
    title: 'name',
    src: 'http://placehold.it/450x300/53777A/ffffff'
},
```

];

http://jsfiddle.net/jimboroberts/p9MLV/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function () {
    this.$().removeWhitespace().collagePlus();
  });
});
```

Comment: No luck, thought it looked great on paper :)